# DaemonException when pushing events to Kinesis

Tags: amazon-kinesis

I am using KPL 0.12.11 for pushing events to kinesis. It was working find at the beginning but recently I receive lots of such errors:

`Exception while adding event to  stream vehicle-stream-qa1, more info com.amazonaws.services.kinesis.producer.DaemonException: The child process has been shutdown and can no longer accept messages..`

any idea?

Answer (score 0):

I found finally the root cause of out of memory issue on my service. After fixing that I see no more problem with KPL.